# Where is the documentation and code synopsis for the GeoIP2 module?

Tags: perl, geoip2

I am trying to update my old Perl script to use the new
[`GeoIP2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/GeoIP2) module
but I can't find any documentation of the actual API calls anywhere.

The README on github, metacpan and the man pages are all the same and don't contain any sample code that I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is on MetaCPAN in
[the normal place](https://metacpan.org/pod/GeoIP2).
You just have to follow the link through to the module you are actually going to use.

[image: Screenshot of the documentation mentioned in the question]

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious.  I followed the links on the line above.